# Create new list containing list x but not elements in list y that are the same as in list x - python

Tags: python, list, intersection, subtraction

I know this question has been discussed before, and I know this is such a novice and easy question, but for some reason I can't wrap my head around the code that would be needed to do this. Here is a practical example that I need this for:

Lets say I contain a tumblr account, and I follow 5 people, of which 3 follow me back.

```
iFollow = [Tom, Richard, Bob, Samantha, Kat]
followsMe = [Samantha, Kat, Bob]
```

Now, I want to ***unfollow*** the people that I follow, however don't follow me back.
So in this example I would want to unfollow **Tom** and **Richard**, because even though I follow them, they don't follow me. I would like to create a list:

```
unfollowThese = [Tom, Richard]
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. I know there is intersect, find the common elements, that would output "Bob", it seems like I want the opposite, I want elements that are common in both lists removed from the new list that I want to make.

I.E. I want elements common in iFollow and followsMe to be removed from unfollowThese, as I don't want to unfollow my followers.

Thanks.

p.s. if you can think of a better title, please change it, I couldn't think of anything to call it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) if order matters:

```
unfollowThese = [ person for person in iFollow if person not in followsMe ]
```

Using [`sets`](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html) if the order of items does not matter:

```
import sets
s1 = sets.Set(iFollow)
unfollowThese = s1.difference(followsMe)
```

Comment: Only one of them needs to be converted to a `set` -- the only advantage of converting both is you can write the difference as `s1 - s2`.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to use the [set difference](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference):

```
unfollowThese = set(iFollow).difference(followsMe)
```

This should also be faster than a list comprehension if `followsMe` is big -- it's linear average time complexity, O(n) in the length of `followsMe`, rather than linear in both the lengths, and so O(n*k).

Just to be complete, note that you can use a `set` to speed up the "order matters" version to lineart time as well:

```
followsMeSet = set(followsMe)
unfollowThese = [person for person in iFollow if person not in followsMeSet]
```

as `set` membership tests are constant average time.

Answer (score 1):

```
iFollow = ['Tom', 'Richard', 'Bob', 'Samantha', 'Kat']
followsMe = ['Samantha', 'Kat', 'Bob']


unfollowThese = [name for name in iFollow if name not in followsMe]

# returns: ['Tom', 'Richard']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
unfollowThese = [x for x in iFollow if x not in followsMe]
```